# xamarin indicator not showing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, indicator

I try show indicator when read data from my web service,
After Search on the web and match with my code, have as the below code to return ListView and show indicator, but indicator don't show.in main page I click on "Show News" button and navigate to new form in new form I have these code after initial form:

```
private async void GetProduct()
{
    var indicator = new ActivityIndicator
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        Color = Color.Black,
        IsVisible = true
    };
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://mySrvice.domain.com/api/news/getlastten");

    indicator.IsRunning = true;
    indicator.IsVisible = true;
    var TProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<News>>(response);
    Label header = new Label
    {
        Text = "Last ten news",
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };

    ListView listView = new ListView
    {
        ItemsSource = TProducts,
        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            // Create views with bindings for displaying each property.
            Label nameLabel = new Label();
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "BNazanin.ttf#Nazanin");
            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.HorizontalTextAlignmentProperty, "Start");



            Image nImage = new Image();
            nImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageURL");

            Label ViewdLabel = new Label();
            ViewdLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Viewed");

            nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.FontFamilyProperty, "BNazanin.ttf#Nazanin");

            // Return an assembled ViewCell.
            return new ViewCell
            {
                View = new StackLayout
                {
                    Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft,
                    Children =
                        {
                            nImage,
                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

                                Spacing = 0,
                                Children =
                                {

                                    nameLabel,
                                    ViewdLabel
                                }
                                }
                        }
                }
            };
        })
    };

    listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        News = (News)e.SelectedItem;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewsDetails(News));
    };
    this.Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children =
        {
            indicator,
            header,
            listView
        }
    };
    indicator.IsRunning = false;
    indicator.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: as soon as you add your content to your page you hide the ActivityIndicator.  Of course it's not showing.  You should really separate fetching the data from building the page.

Comment: Thanks Jason, how can I resolve that, in above code i think show indicator and after show listview hide it. which code must be change?

Comment: NOTHING you are doing is visible until you add it to the page by assigning the Content property

Comment: I disabled " //indicator.IsRunning = false;
        //indicator.IsVisible = false;" but not showing!after the news show indicator show.I want show indicator before showing my news

Answer (score 0):

As another user stated in the comments, the `ActivityIndicator` does not appear unless you add it to the page. You are adding it to the page at the end of `GetProduct()` and immediately making it invisible, hence it is *never* visible, either because it has not been added, yet, or because it was made invisible.

There are several possibilities you could achieve what you want. The simplest might be to add the `ActivityIndicator` at the beginning of `GetProducts()`

```
var indicator = new ActivityIndicator
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    Color = Color.Black,
    IsVisible = true,
    IsRunning = true
};
this.Content = indicator; 

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://mySrvice.domain.com/api/news/getlastten");
```

(`IsRunning` is set immediately, because I'd assume that you'd like the indicator to run *while* you are getting the products from the server, not after.)

You won't need the indicator in the final stack layout, hence you could set `Content` with

```
this.Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        header,
        listView
    }
};
```

*On a side note*: Using XAML and MVVM can be very helpful with those things.